# Ear and war for jsf1.1 with tomahawk and ajsx4jsf

Tags: java, jsf, jakarta-ee, ear, ajax4jsf

I am developing an application with ejb and jsf with tomahawk and ajax4jsf and jsf-api jsf-impl jars at WEB-inf/lib folder..

I have put other jars like iText and POI jars at ear root and it works fine with manifest in war pointing at the ear root..

Do i need to put jsf-api.jar at ear root?
What other jars should I put in WEB-INF/lib folder..(Should I put 'commons' jar in WEB-INF/lib or at EAR root..? )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on your runtime environment, what libraries you need. What webserver/container do you use? Because of the different web- and application server, there are different libraries provided by the vendors. Sometimes you have to configure your own jars, sometimes not. I think  with Apache Tomcat 7 you have to add the JSF files to your lib directory. But by using JBoss or Glassfish you don't need it, because they are Java EE 6 (Web Profile) certified. By the way, what JSF, EJB and a4j version do use? It looks like some old stuff. I guess you are using an application server, because of EJB. In that case you don't have to add the libraries of JSF and Apache Commons, because the AS will provide it usually.

I would recommend to create a Maven Project. It is not so difficult at all and you can define the libraries in one XML file.

Comment: Yes.. it is old stuff..I am using myfaces-api-1.1.5.jar ajax4jsf1.1.1 and tomahawk-1.1.6.jar,tomahawk-sandbox-1.1.7-SNAPSHOT.jar..The server is OCJ4 app server..I am using ant build..

Comment: Do you have access to the OCJ4 App Server? You could try to install myfaces like it is described in the [myfaces wiki](http://wiki.apache.org/myfaces/Installation_and_Configuration), there is also a part for OCJ4.